# How can I find groups in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, nibabel

I have a binary 3d array that has small groups of `1` and large groups of `1`. I want to search the array and when a `1` is found I want to search the surrounding values in the `x,y,z` directions and count how many `1` are connected. If there are less than `x` amount of `1` I want to set that group to 0. The entire 3d array consists of `1` and `0`.

Array Example:

```
img  = np.array([[[0,0,0,1,0],
                  [0,0,0,1,1]],
                 [[0,0,0,1,0],
                  [0,0,0,0,0]]])
```

There is a group of `1` directly next to each other in the x,y,z directions. In my code for this scenario the group is `num_group = 4`. Since that group is smaller than 10 I want to make that group `0`.

```
img  = np.array([[[0,0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0,0]],
                 [[0,0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0,0]]])
```

There are 1-2 very large and distinct groups in my arrays. I want to only have those large groups in my final array.

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
import os, sys

x = 10

img = nib.load(\\test.nii).get_fdata()
print(img.shape)
>>>(512,512,30)
size_x, size_y, size_z = vol.shape

for z_slices in range(size_z):
    for y_slices in range(size_y):
        for x_slices in range(size_x):
            num_group = (Find a 1 and count how many 1s are connected)
            if num_group < x:
                num_group = 0
```

Comment: How is the code relevant to the question?

Comment: How do you define "group"? What type of connectivity are we talking about?

Comment: Are you OK with just doing a convolution?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am just showing my current approach/thought process. I am open to any approach.

Comment: Your code and prose are disconnected. Describe what you want in detail and explain how the code does/does not fulfill that. There's not much of a question otherwise.

Comment: What do you mean by `groups of 1s`? Sounds like a [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) case.

Comment: @QuangHoang. OP is likely looking for matlab's regionprops. I think skimage has something like that. But right now the question is very poorly posed.

Comment: I have updated the question and shown an example. Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use skimage for this:

```
from skimage.measure import regionprops,label
sz = 10  #this is your set threshold
xyz = np.vstack([i.coords for i in regionprops(label(img)) if i.area<sz]) #finding regions and coordinates of regions smaller than threshold
img[tuple(xyz.T)]=0 #setting small regions to 0
```

output:

```
[[[0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]]]
```